# get child nodes of node WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created this UserControl

```cs
    public partial class Dropdown : UserControl
    {
        public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        private void loadSuccess(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TitleBlock.Text = Title;
        }
        public Dropdown() 
        {
            Loaded += loadSuccess;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Lamprey.UserControls.Dropdown"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Lamprey.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="17"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text=">" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="#FFC7C7C7"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TitleBlock" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
        <ListBox x:Name="Items" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="White">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

It is meant to be used like this

```xml
                <usercontrols:Dropdown Title="History">
                    <ListBoxItem>
                        <TextBlock>Example</TextBlock>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </usercontrols:Dropdown>
```

I am trying to figure out how I can get a list of children of the `<Dropdown>` so I can move them into the Items `<ListBox>`.

The end goal is for any children addded to `<Dropdown>` to be automatically added to the `<ListBox>` named Items. That way, the entire listbox can be hidden when the dropdown is closed, and shown when the dropdown is opened.

Comment: your Dropdown should inherit ItemsControl instead of UserControl

Comment: Why not simply use a ListBox directly with a ControlTemplate?

Answer (score 1):

The key is to define a collection dependency property and bind it to the `ListBox`. This property must be declared as the control's content property in order to be able to add items to it implicitly in XAML.

1. Define a custom non-generic collection or use an existing one

**DropDownItemCollection.cs**

```cs
public class DropDownItemCollection : List<object>
{ }
```

2. Define a dependency property of the non-generic collection type
3. Declare this property as the content property using the `ContentProperty` attribute to decorate the property owner
4. Optionally, define a `DataTemplate` type property e.g., `ItemTemplate` to allow templating the items using an explicit `DataTemplate`

**DropDown.xaml.cs**

```cs
[ContentProperty(nameof(DropDown.DropDownItems))]
public partial class DropDown : UserControl
{
  public DropDownItemCollection DropDownItems
  {
    get => (DropDownItemCollection)GetValue(DropDownItemsProperty);
    set => SetValue(DropDownItemsProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty DropDownItemsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
      "DropDownItems",
      typeof(DropDownItemCollection),
      typeof(DropDown),
      new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
  {
    get => (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty);
    set => SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
      "ItemTemplate",
      typeof(DataTemplate),
      typeof(DropDown),
      new PropertyMetadata(default));


  public DropDown()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DropDownItems = new DropDownItemCollection();
  }
}
```

5. Bind the internal `ListBox` to the new `DropDownItems` property

**DropDown.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl>
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DropDownItems}"
           ItemTemplate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=ItemTemplate}" />
</UserControl>
```

**Example**

```xml
<!-- 
  Since the collection is of type object you can add anything to the collection.
  The ItemTemplate property allows to explicitly template the item layout.
-->
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DroptDownItemTemplate">
      <Grid>
        <Border Background="OrangeRed" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <DropDown ItemTemplate={StaticResource DroptDownItemTemplate}">
    <sys:String>Item 1</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Item 2</sys:String>
  </DropDown>
</Window>
```

**Remarks**
You can skip all this when extending `ListBox` instead of `UserControl`. Doing so, your control will support item creation in XAML and templating out of the box.
Hiding and showing the internal `ListBox` will lead to changes in the layout and therfore result in ugly content resizing. You should consider to host the `ListBox` (or in case of extending `ListBox` the `ItemsPresenter`) inside a `Popup` to create the flyout that overlays instead of resizing.